# Serving GWT app from ARM-based machine

Tags: tomcat, gwt, arm

I have an ARM-based platform and I'd like to use it to serve GWT application. On x86 I'd go with Tomcat to serve pages, but what options do I have on ARM architecture?

Although GWT is preferred it isn't a must-have but I don't want to switch from Java to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can serve a GWT app even from a plain web server (it's just a bunch of static files).
- If you want to use GWTRPC, you'll need a Java servlet container. As long as your server has a JRE, you should be able to run Tomcat or Jetty or ...
- Looking into [debian packages](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/web/tomcat5.5), it tells me, that Tomcat 5.5 is for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding option no 2 I found Cacao and OpenJDK as options to consider. Both should work on ARM architecture and have JRE.